# Performance: Processing large JSON in js/php and storing it to MySQL or process it in MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

What is the most efficient way to store a large JSON in MySQL database using PHP?

As I understand it my options are:

1. Process it in JS - make an `AJAX` call to `POST` data (through a php script) in the database for every every key/value I want to store (can't pass the JSON directly to php - throws object size error and I don't want to mess with php.ini)
2. Pass it as text to PHP , decode it and then do a `mysqli_querry` in a loop for every key/value pair I want to store.
3. Pass it as text to MySQL and handle it there with MySQL built-in JSON functions.

What option would be more perfomant?

Comment: 1) Specify **precise** MySQL version. 2) Show an example of your JSON and final data state after importing (the content of MySQL table), also provide complete CREATE TABLE script for the destination table.

Comment: And define what you mean by performant.  Parsing the data into a well structured model will improve the performance of your queries and reduce the load on your machines, if that is what you are after.  Storing JSON raw in MySQL will be easier on your developers.  In general, I feel that human time is more important than machine time, but it depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you need to decide which fields of the JSON string that you will be searching on via SQL.  Put those fields into their own columns.  Then the JSON (with or without copies of those fields) is simply an opaque `TEXT` or `JSON` column.  It will be written and read as a unit; the client will unpack as needed.

PHP has decent functions for handling JSON.  I suggest sticking with UTF-8 encoding of the JSON and using `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`.  If stored into `TEXT`, be sure to have `utf8mb4`; the collation does not matter.  (The MySQL/MariaDB details vary with the exact version you are using.)

You ask for "performant".  By breaking out the columns needed for searching, MySQL indexing will work much faster than dynamically picking apart JSON.  (Again the version matters when considering indexing JSON fields and/or using `GENERATED` columns.)

"Key-value" (EAV) schema is clumsy and bad for performance.  So I hope you don't need to create arbitrary tests across multiple key-value pairs.  I discuss that further here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav